# Python : dash-leaflet specific color for each polygon

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, dash-leaflet

I can not set color of each polygon.
I can set all polygons color for example to black or blue but i can not adjust them one by one
Actually i want to set their color by a column value of pandas for each record
Eg: if value was higher than 100 the color would be red and if it was lower than 100 color would be blue for each record.
The java code that dash-leaflet official site published does not work.
My code:

```
from typing import Dict
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_leaflet as dl
import dash_leaflet.express as dlx
from dash import Dash
from dash_extensions.javascript import arrow_function, assign
from dash_extensions.javascript import *
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import json
geo2 ={"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"unique_id": "Azarbayejaan","color_Prop": "24666232.558139537"},"geometry":{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[51.3918314, 35.6961673], [51.3919641, 35.6961606], [51.404183, 35.6955455], [51.4040877, 35.6950063], [51.4038705, 35.6938181], [51.4032683, 35.6904263], [51.4026943, 35.6870017], [51.3950862, 35.6879227], [51.3928801, 35.688208], [51.3928251, 35.6886475], [51.3927112, 35.6893468], [51.3925019, 35.6908837], [51.392451, 35.6913716], [51.3921975, 35.6933267], [51.3918314, 35.6961673]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"unique_id": "Aazari","color_Prop": "15226991.228070175"},"geometry":{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[51.344179, 35.6655131], [51.3544421, 35.6637675], [51.3547968, 35.6639669], [51.3550972, 35.6640764], [51.3554083, 35.6641522], [51.3564748, 35.6643412], [51.3560333, 35.6674078], [51.3558603, 35.6685006], [51.3557165, 35.6696512], [51.3529766, 35.6706209], [51.352738, 35.6706535], [51.3524591, 35.6706579], [51.3496078, 35.669174], [51.3474084, 35.6681367], [51.3465394, 35.6677009], [51.3460888, 35.6674482], [51.3453271, 35.6673936], [51.3450346, 35.6672303], [51.3449337, 35.6671658], [51.3446672, 35.6669949], [51.3445277, 35.6666898], [51.3443802, 35.6662824], [51.3442488, 35.6658574], [51.344179, 35.6655131]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"unique_id": "Aaraaraat","color_Prop": "451765700.0"},"geometry":{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[51.3952472, 35.7749876], [51.396135, 35.7751617], [51.3971918, 35.7756883], [51.3990157, 35.7767873], [51.3995602, 35.7770963], [51.4000778, 35.7773117], [51.4005794, 35.7774684], [51.401148, 35.7775293], [51.4017837, 35.7775206], [51.4026957, 35.7774162], [51.4037578, 35.7772334], [51.4046456, 35.7771311], [51.4053698, 35.7769396], [51.4060618, 35.7766806], [51.4061182, 35.7752292], [51.4058178, 35.7742369], [51.4049809, 35.772966], [51.4038651, 35.771743], [51.4035325, 35.7712381], [51.4033501, 35.770876799999996], [51.4032321, 35.7704329], [51.4023738, 35.7663893], [51.4022746, 35.7654208], [51.4009469, 35.7661804], [51.3994851, 35.7670683], [51.3981091, 35.7677147], [51.3963898, 35.7679149], [51.3968672, 35.7699149], [51.39689, 35.7702827], [51.3968082, 35.7708028], [51.3967975, 35.7709878], [51.3964046, 35.772163], [51.396253, 35.7724611], [51.3958131, 35.7730465], [51.3957032, 35.7732532], [51.3956133, 35.7734763], [51.3952472, 35.7749876]]]}}
            
    ]}
connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:*@localhost:*/db')

df = pd.read_sql_table('table', connection)
value = df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['Price_Meter'].mean()
value = value.reset_index()


classes = [0, 200, 500, 1000, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000]
colorscale = ['#FFEDA0', '#FED976', '#FEB24C', '#FD8D3C', '#FC4E2A', '#E31A1C', '#BD0026', '#800026']
style = dict(weight=2, opacity=1, dashArray='3', fillOpacity=0.7)
# Create colorbar.
ctg = ["{}+".format(cls, classes[i + 1]) for i, cls in enumerate(classes[:-1])] + ["{}+".format(classes[-1])]
colorbar = dlx.categorical_colorbar(categories=ctg, colorscale=colorscale, width=300, height=30, position="bottomleft")








json_object = json.dumps(geo)
df1 = pd.read_json(json_object)
df1['properties'] = df1['properties'].astype(str)
value['Neighbourhood'] = value['Neighbourhood'].astype(str)
value['Price_Meter'] = value['Price_Meter'].astype(str)
df1['properties'] = df1['properties'].str[15:-2]
dict1 = {'properties': 'Neighbourhood'}
df1.rename(columns=dict1,
          inplace=True)
new = pd.merge(df1,value, how='inner', on='Neighbourhood')
dict2 = {'Neighbourhood': 'propertiestemp'}
new.rename(columns=dict2,
          inplace=True)
new['properties'] = '"unique_id": "' + new['propertiestemp'] + '"' + ',' + '"color_Prop": "' + new['Price_Meter'] + '"'
new['output'] = '{"type":"' + new['type'].astype(str) + '","properties":{' + new['properties'].astype(str) + '},"geometry":' + new['geometry'].astype(str) + '},'
new.drop(['propertiestemp', 'Price_Meter', 'type', 'geometry', 'properties'], axis=1, inplace=True)
tolis = new['output'].tolist()
out = ''
out = out.join(tolis)
out = "{'type': 'FeatureCollection','features': [" + out + "]}"

style_handle = assign("""function(feature, context){
    const {classes, colorscale, style, colorProp} = context.props.hideout;  // get props from hideout
    const value = feature.properties[colorProp];  // get value the determines the color
    for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; ++i) {
        if (value > classes[i]) {
            style.fillColor = colorscale[i];  // set the fill color according to the class
        }
    }
    return style;
}""")


# Create geojson.
geojson = dl.GeoJSON(data=geo2,  # url to geojson file
                     options=dict(style=dict(style_handle)),  # how to style each polygon
                     zoomToBounds=True,  # when true, zooms to bounds when data changes (e.g. on load)
                     zoomToBoundsOnClick=True,  # when true, zooms to bounds of feature (e.g. polygon) on click
                     hoverStyle=arrow_function(dict(weight=5, color='#666', dashArray='')),  # style applied on hover
                     #hideout=dict(colorscale=colorscale, classes=classes, style=style, colorProp='color_Prop'),
                     id="geojson")

# Create app.
app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([dl.Map(children=[dl.TileLayer(), geojson, colorbar])],#, info
                      style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"}, id="map")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When i run it i get this error in dash debug section:
No match for [dashExtensions.default.function1] in the global window object.

When i remove style_handle it works fine but i want to set each polygon color by its numeric value.
Can i do it in dash and python?
Thx

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post self-contained example? The current code does not run as it requires access to a database.

Comment: i moved to reactjs with Django because dash was very slow on loading thanks for help @emher